# How do I print rgb text in a terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, colors

I am wanting to try making a 3D renderer in the console using python. In order to make this look half decent, I need to be able to print multiple shades of whatever color. Is there a way to do this with rgb values?

I have used termcolor and played with colorama before, but I don’t think ascii can do this.

I want this to run on Windows’ console host, through cpython, cmd, and/or PowerShell. Ubuntu support would be okay and I’m not worried about OS X.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print colored text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi Not up front. I managed to dig my way through there to a Wikipedia article that mentioned something similar to what I want. I’ll look at it and see if it works.

Comment: Most terminal do not have many colours. 16 is the normal. The "256" colours are often not compatible (and discouraged by some). But because of your host environment requirement, I think you are looking the wrong way: just add yourself a windows "console", where you have control. [Terminals are here to be used across very different kind of machines]